# Is camera equipment and bags in general allowed on NYC Observation Decks?

Tags: new-york-city, photography, observation-decks

I am going to see Ball Drop this New Year's Eve with three of my friends. We also plan to do some sightseeing and take some pictures on Jan 3 & 4. Two of us are into photography.

Some of our planned stuff is:

1. Top of the Rock
2. Brooklyn Bridge
3. Ellis Island/ Lady Liberty
4. Times Square and some local landmarks in Manhattan like Rockefeller Center, plus some restaurants.
5. Possibly Empire State Observation Deck.

`Question`: Are bags and camera equipment like folding tripods allowed on Observation Deck?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where is a tripod allowed from high up in New York City?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/23395/where-is-a-tripod-allowed-from-high-up-in-new-york-city)

Answer (score 6):

Cameras for personal use should be fine at the Empire State Building, but tripods, professional cameras, etc., will probably not get past security screening. Nor will their cases, your carry-on luggage...

From the [Empire State Building official FAQ](http://www.esbnyc.com/faq):

> The items listed are not permitted in the Empire State Building. Do not carry any of these items into the security screening area. Items that are confiscated may not be returned. Please note that this list is not exhaustive, so if you are unsure about an item, please do not bring it. Any questions and uncertainties should be referred to the Security Officers on duty.
>
> - All weapons, including firearms, ammunition, knives, swords, scissors, mace, any dangerous items and any dual-use items that could be dangerous are strictly prohibited in the Empire State Building.
> - Glass items, including bottles, glasses, marbles, etc.
> - Alcoholic beverages
> - Cans, bottles, flasks, etc.
> - Professional cameras, equipment and camera stands: mono-pods, bi-pods and tri-pods
> - Sports equipment such as skateboards, roller skates, golf clubs, baseball bats, hockey sticks, baseballs, footballs, tennis balls, etc.
> - Marking instruments, including spray paint and markers
> - Musical instruments
> - Large packages, suitcases, carry-on luggage and other such parcels.
> - Costumes and masks

Comment: What do they define as a "professional camera"?

Comment: @vclaw They don't define that. It's apparently somewhat discretionary. But see also http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/14374/3221

Answer (score 2):

I've gone up the empire state building with my pro gear, had no problems; but you will not be allowed to bring any-type of tripod nor monopod & if the rules had changed .. then I would advice you to go to the Observation deck in the Freedom towers or Rockefeller Centers (top of the rock)